# Odoo 10 - Change name of product_template with .name, change done in database but not in the web interface

Tags: odoo

I am trying to change the name of a given Odoo product.

I do:

```
new_product = foo_product_id.copy()
```

which creates a new product_template from foo_product_id, which is named 'FOO', then I do:

```
new_product.name = 'FOO PLUS BAR'
```

if I check database for new_product id name is 'FOO PLUS BAR' but in the web interface it still appears as 'FOO (copy)'.

I have tried to restart the server and refresh the browser CTRL+F5, still old name.

Any tip is really welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

If it shows in your database as "FOO PLUS BAR" then it should show up correctly via the interface. I'm assuming in this case that you are some how looking at the `product.product` record instead of the `product.template` record. Check your `product.product` table and see if it has the correct value as well.

Comment: product.product has no name column. I guess it is because I am not using product variants. I double check everything.   # select * from product_product;
 id  |        create_date         | weight | default_code | product_tmpl_id | message_last_post | create_uid | write_uid | barcode | volume |         write_date         | active
-----+----------------------------+--------+--------------+-----------------+-------------------+------------+-----------+---------+--------+----------------------------+--------

Comment: The .copy() and .name attribute change happens inside a .create method of another model, in case it makes a difference.

Answer (score -2):

Try changing name_get function, inherit it from product class.

Comment: The `name_get` function already pulls from `name`. So there should be no reason to override.